# How to access sqlite database from webserver and insert record using web services in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am developing one application in CN1 that has to do with database, I want the user to enter a pin generated for them. once the user entered the valid pin, the apps will be activated for usage. The problem am having now is how to access the database using webservices. I have followed the webservices wizard tutorial, but all my effort was futile.
This is my snippet code.

```
  private static final String DESTINATION_URL = "http://localhost:8085/CBT_PINS/folder/PINS.db";    

 ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest(DESTINATION_URL) {
 @Override
 protected void handleException(Exception err) {
 Log.e(err);
 Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
 ToastBar.showErrorMessage("An error occured while connecting to the server: " + err);
  });
  }

@Override
protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Error code from the server: " + code + "\n" + message);
});
}

};
req.setPost(false);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);
```

Please help me out. I dont know what to do next. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details on what's failing? Is it failing in the simulator? Notice that the URL is local to the machine so it won't run on the device. What do you see in terms of errors? Did you use the network monitor to see what is passed back/forth?

Comment: I have posted the details of my code. Thanks Sir

Comment: Do you want your app to connect to a remote database using internet connection or you want it to access a database bundled with the app? From the code you posted below, you are doing it all wrong... mixing 2 different methods of accessing data from a database.

Comment: I want my app to connect to remote database using internet connection

Comment: FYI You need to edit your question and provide the details there, you added an answer by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, Author of CN1. This is the full code below. I am using tomcat server on the local machine to test on the simulator. I am very sure if it works for me on the local machine's server, it will definitely work on the web server

```
private static final String DESTINATION_URL = "http://localhost:8085/CBT_PINS/folder/PINS.db";    

 ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest(DESTINATION_URL) {
 @Override

Database  myDataBase = com.codename1.db.Database.openOrCreate(DESTINATION_URL);
   Cursor c = myDataBase.executeQuery("select pin from PIN_TABLE where id =  1" );

     if (c.next()) {
        Row r = c.getRow();

         String pin = r.getString(0);

    Dialog.show("valid pin", pin, "Ok", "Ok");

    } else if    (!c.next()) {
        Dialog.show("Invalid pin", "keep off", "ok", "ok");      


                }


 protected void handleException(Exception err) {
 Log.e(err);
 Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
ToastBar.showErrorMessage("An error occured while connecting to the server: " + err);
 });
}

@Override
protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Error code from the server: " + code + "\n" +   message);
});
}

};
req.setPost(false);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);
```

This is the error code generated for me when I ran the code:

```
WARNING: Apple will no longer accept http URL connections from applications you tried to connect to http://localhost:8085/CBT_PINS/folder/PINS.db to learn more check out https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'C:\Users\EMMY_OLUWASEGUN\.cn1/database/http://localhost:8085/CBT_PINS/folder/PINS.db': 'C:\Users\EMMY_OLUWASEGUN\.cn1\database\http:' does not exist
[Network Thread] 0:0:0,0 - Codename One revisions: 375ed2c938445450f0983f0d18235f61e793a7ee2004

[Network Thread] 0:0:0,0 - Exception: java.io.IOException - path to 'C:\Users\EMMY_OLUWASEGUN\.cn1/database/http://localhost:8085/CBT_PINS/folder/PINS.db': 'C:\Users\EMMY_OLUWASEGUN\.cn1\database\http:' does not exist
Rendering frame took too long 187 milliseconds
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:156)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:105)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:113)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.openOrCreateDB(JavaSEPort.java:7548)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.openOrCreate(Display.java:3690)
at com.codename1.db.Database.openOrCreate(Database.java:59)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication$1.readResponse(MyApplication.java:283)
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:483)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.io.IOException: path to 'C:\Users\EMMY_OLUWASEGUN\.cn1/database/http://localhost:8085/CBT_PINS/folder/PINS.db': 'C:\Users\EMMY_OLUWASEGUN\.cn1\database\http:' does not exist
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.openOrCreateDB(JavaSEPort.java:7554)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.openOrCreate(Display.java:3690)
at com.codename1.db.Database.openOrCreate(Database.java:59)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication$1.readResponse(MyApplication.java:283)
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:483)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you aren't accessing a webservice. You are trying to open a database with an http URL:

> SQLException: path to 'C:\Users\EMMY_OLUWASEGUN.cn1/database/http://localhost:8085/CBT_PINS/folder/PINS.db'

Triggered by:

```
Database  myDataBase = com.codename1.db.Database.openOrCreate(DESTINATION_URL);
```

The Database API is local to the device and not remote a webservice is something completely different.